# Change back css after .slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this issue: I want to set background color on hover element and slidetoggle a div inside it. But when item slide out i would like to set another background color to the element. Check the code:

```
<div class="menu segundoitem institucional"><span class="textoMenu">Institucional</span>

<div id="submenu-01">Institucional</div>

</div>
```

And the Jquery

```
$(".institucional").hover(function(){
    $('#submenu-01').stop().slideToggle();
    $(this).css("background", "#380606");
});
```

As you can see, ".institucional" background is set to #380606, but when mouse leave and #submenu-01 disapear, ".institucional" keeps with the background #380606... I would like to make it background #FFFFFF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two seperate functions for mouseenter and mouseleave, and you can set whatever you want

```
$(".institucional").on({
    mouseenter : function() {
        $('#submenu-01').stop().slideDown(400);
        $(this).css("background", "#380606");
    },
    mouseleave : function() {
        var self = this;
        $('#submenu-01').stop().slideUp(400, function() {
            $(self).css("background", "#FFF");
        });
    }
});
```